# Path disconnected homotopic equivalent spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that two path connected homotopic spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups. But if $X \simeq_f Y$ and $X$ path disconnected ($\implies$ Y path disconnected) what can we say about their fundamental groups? Is there an example showing $\pi_1(X,x) \not \cong \pi_1(Y, f(x))$? Also does $\pi_1(X,x) \cong \pi_1(Y, f(x))$ hold under some assumption weaker assumption than path connectivity?

Comment: The question here is if you have a disconnected space, how are you going about defining $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ anyway? Your choice of basepoint in each connected component may change what $\pi_1$ is, so here $\pi_1(X)$ may not be well defined.

Comment: I am considering connected, but path disconnected spaces.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Path connectedness implies connectedness. Regardless, I meant "path disconnected" in my previous answer.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Note the OP said path *disconnected*, i.e. connected but not path connected

Comment: My bad, I hadn't heard this terminology for that kind of space before! Sorry OP

Comment: @john If $f$ is your homotopy (I think this is what your notation means... you should clarify) then you can restrict the path-connected components, in which case you get a homotopy equivalence once you take restrictions (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725717/homotopy-equivalence-induces-bijection-between-path-components)) so you can probably conclude $\pi(X,x) \cong \pi(Y,f(x))$ where $f$ is now the induced homotopy equivalence on the path component of $x$